# Как передать выбранные параметры текста из второй формы в первую, не нарушая принципов ООП?

Tags: c#, ооп

Как передать выбранные параметры текста из второй формы в первую, по нажатию кнопки "применить" во второй форме, не нарушая принципов ООП?

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void font_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 font_dialog = new Form2();
            font_dialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Кнопка сохранения файла в заранее указанную папку
        private void save_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\my_dir"); // Создание директории

            // Запись
            string lines = "" + textBox1.Text;
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\my_dir\my_txt.txt", lines);

            MessageBox.Show("Файл сохранен!");            
        }

        private void exit_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Список шрифтов
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (comboBox1.Text)
            {
                case "Arial":
                    Font font_1 = new Font("Arial", this.Font.Size);
                    comboBox1.Font = font_1;
                    break;

                case "Courier New":
                    Font font_2 = new Font("Courier New", this.Font.Size);
                    comboBox1.Font = font_2;
                    break;

                case "Times New Roman":
                    Font font_3 = new Font("Times New Roman", this.Font.Size);
                    comboBox1.Font = font_3;
                    break;

                default:
                    Font def_font = new Font("Arial", this.Font.Size);
                    comboBox1.Font = def_font;
                    break;
            }

        }

        // Кнопка применения параметров шрифта
        private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, идея с тремя захардкоженными шрифтами и текстбоксом по меньшей мере странная.

Answer (score 8):

ИМХО, предложенный вариант с глобальным `FormValuesHolder` противоречит всем принципам ООП: он добавляет временную связанность между объектами и может привести к проблемам сопровождения.

- *Решение нарушает принцип инкапсуляции*. Где здесь сокрытие информации? Открытое поле без поведения не способствует сокрытию информации.
- *Отсутствие абстракции*. Статическое поле не повышает уровень абстракции.
- *Отсутствие поведения*. В ООП данные сами по себе не хранятся. С ними должно быть связано некоторое поведение. Поведение у свойства типа `string` с точки зрения моделирования решения отсутствует.

Теперь, альтернативные решение.

1. Если нажатие кнопки "применить" второй формы закрывает ее.

В этом случае, в классе `Form2` достаточно объвить открытое свойтсов нужного типа и устанавливать его в событии `OK_Click`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        private void font_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 font_dialog = new Form2();
            if (font_dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               // Мы знаем, что кнопка OK была нажата, пользователь 
               // не отменил ввод.
               // Используем новые свойства шрифта
               Console.WriteLine(font_dialog.NewFont);
            }
        }
}
```

Обычно первый вариант подходит, поскольку кнопка OK обычно закрывает форму.

Но если, по какой-то неведомой мне причине такой вариант не подходит, то можно во вторую форму добавить событие, которое будет генерироваться при выборе нового шрифта.

```
// Да, имена форм тоже разумно сразу же давать осмысленные
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
  public void FontButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Да, подчеркивания не приветствуются в именах полей/переменных
    var fontDialog = new FontDialog();
    fontDialog.NewFontSelected += HandleNewFont;
    fontDialog.ShowDialog();
  }

  private void HandleNewFont(object sender, NewFontSelectedEventArgs ea)
  {
    // Обратаываем выбранный новый шрифт
  }
}

public class NewFontSelectedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public string NewFont {get; set;}
}

public partial class FontDialogForm : Form
{
  public event EventHandler<NewFontSelectedEventArgs> NewFontSelected;

  private void OnNewFontSelected(string newFont)
  {
    var handler = NewFontSelected;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, new NewFontSelectedEventArgs{NewFont = newFont};
  }
  // все тоже самое

  // Кнопка применения параметров шрифта
  private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // уведомляем подписчиков о выбранном новом шрифте
    OnNeFontSelected(newFont);
  }
}
```

Да, если посмотреть на стандартный [`FontDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.fontdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), то легко можно будет заметить в нем сходство с предложенным решением. Вот пример использования стандартного диалога для изменения шрифта:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
    fontDialog1.ShowColor = true;

    fontDialog1.Font = textBox1.Font;
    fontDialog1.Color = textBox1.ForeColor;

    if(fontDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel )
    {
       textBox1.Font = fontDialog1.Font ;
       textBox1.ForeColor = fontDialog1.Color;
    }
 }
```

[Cap mode on]Никаких глобальных статических классов, которые содержат промежуточный новый фонт![Cap mode off].

Comment: Эм, я как-то не вижу здесь нарушения инкапсуляции, полиморфизма, наследования и абстракции. Это нехорошее решение, не спорю, но разве тут есть нарушение принципов ООП? Там есть нарушение принципов хорошей архитектуры, которые к ООП никакого отношения не имеют.

Comment: Я так понимаю, речь идет о моей фразе в начале ответа... Глобальный ответ - это не-ОО-решение. Совсем. Это из мира структурного программирования. И да, глобальные объект с открытым свойством нарушает ООП: это нарушение инкапсуляции (где здесь сокрытие информации?), отсутствие абстракции (где она в этом решении?), отсутствие поведения (есть только данные). Так что оно очень много чего нарушает;)

Comment: Существование принципа абстракции не подразумевает его обязательную реализацию, равно как и с инкапсуляцией. И вообще там формально сеттер и геттер.

Comment: Так из всех классических принципов ООП здесь не нарушается только наследование, которое здесь не применимо. Другими словами, здесь нарушаются все применимые в данном случае каноны ООП, и вам этого мало?

Comment: Они не нарушаются, их здесь нет, потому что они не нужны, как и наследование. Здесь не нужна абстракция, потому что нет многоуровневости. Здесь нет наследования, потому что пример банальный и наследовать нечего. Единственное поле скрыто за аксессорами.

Comment: "Они не нарушаются". Посмотрите, как был поставлен вопрос изначально. Требовался совет по ОО решению. Первый ответ не содержал ОО-решения, его там вообще не было, вы правы. Я же предложил ОО решение. К нему у Вас вопросы есть?

Comment: Для того, чтобы связывать два объекта через третий, нужны причины. Какие в данном случае причины? А с применением вашего подхода получилось следующее: было - о данных знала только Form1, стало - о данных, через публичный статический класс, знает все приложение. Разве в этом была необходимость?

Comment: Ничего не понял. Наличие третьего объекта делает связь по передаче данных от одного объекта к другому - неявной. Это плохо. В текущем решении форма 1 уже знает о существовании формы 2. Прямая передача данных, как предложено, является самым простым решением.
З.Ы. На всякий случай: я критикую подход со статическим объектом, а не отстаиваю его.

Comment: @Memoizer или это не мне вопрос был?

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov не вам. Надо было процитировать адресата :) но я специально сказал о подходе с публичным статическим классом.

Comment: @Memoizer Да там такая перепалка в комментариях была, что я не сразу понял, что не на мой счет комментарий:)))

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov, зачем отдельное свойство в форме? Почему бы просто не переопределить метод ShowDialog (который и так вызывется для показа формы), чтобы он предоставлял необходимое значение?

Comment: @Qwertiy: можно и так, но проблема в том, что в этом случае придется завернуть DialogResult в другой класс. Можно, но нужно ли? Это же локальная связка двух форм, здесь подойдет любой вменяемый вариант прямого общения между ними. Нравится более чистый вариант? Не вопрос. Но я в таки случаях использовал самый простой путь: добавлял свойство и все. Это проще, чем создавать новый тип данных.

Comment: Нужно ли заворачивать? В куче случаев можно обойтись и без этого. Например, вернуть старое значение (если оно известно форме) или null (да, null'ы ты не любишь), если была нажата отмена. Другой весьма вероятный вариант, что форма, будет получать некую модель, которая в ней и будет редактироваться. Соответственно, при показе она копирует значения из модели в поля, а при нажатии ok - обратно из полей в модель. Тогда возвращать можно обычный DialogResult. При особом желании, можно передать модель ref-параметром и создавать новый экземпляр, но я бы не стал так делать без особых оснований.

Comment: Ну, я ж не спорю, что есть множество способов. Здесь полное отсутствие контекста в вопросе, чтобы давать более точные советы.

Comment: Куча кода (вероятно даже весь имеющийся, но недописанный) - это полное отсутствие контекста? о_О

Answer (score 3):

Я бы больше говорил не о нарушении ООП, а о нарушении общих принципов дизайна программ.

Проблема вашего кода заключается в том, что бизнес-логика и представление объединены и перемешаны. В результате окно почему-то знает о том, где и как хранятся данные, хотя это на самом деле вопрос для уровня модели.

Таким образом, правильный подход мне кажется следующим:

1. Первая форма запрашивает параметры у своей модели/VM (в зависимости от выбранного паттерна организации программы).
2. Модель/VM обнаруживает, что эти данные нужно запросить в UI, и инициирует показ второй формы.
3. После закрытия второй формы информация есть у модели/VM, и она доставляется первой форме.

Comment: Это верно, но для очень простых случаев (наподобие выбора шрифта) таким разделением, как мне кажется, можно пренебречь. Особенно в WinForms, где с MVVM не так чтобы очень.

Comment: @Memoizer: Для простой программы не обязательно и следование принципам ООП. Я расценивал код из вопроса как упрощённый пример.

Comment: @Memoizer для WinForms очень хорошо работает MVP.

Comment: @Memorize, наоборот код упростится, если ввести отдельный объект бизнес-логики, который будет управлять вызовом форм и собирать данные.

Comment: @VladD, по сути ответ про модели - хороший. Просто можно упростить, добавить третий объект B, который будет содержать формы, как поля.  B.form1; B.from2

Comment: @VladD: Model-View Separation - это очень важная техника. Но, судя по вопросу топикстартера, этой темой еще несколько рано ему заниматься... ИМХО, выделение моделей в подобном коде приводит к создании всемогуторов.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov: ну, уж всемогутор можно подвергнуть дальнейшей декомпозиции. ИМХО важно то, что не окна/presentation layer, а бизнес-логика занимается перекидыванием информации.

Comment: @VladD: я полностью согласен с предложенным подходом. Я просто не уверен, что тапикстартер дорос до этого.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov: Тогда ответ будет ему «на вырост» :-)

Answer (score 1):

Cделайте отдельный static-класс - хранилище.

```
public static class FormValuesHolder
{
   static string _str1 = string.Empty;

   public static string Str1
   {
       get { return _str1; }
       set { _str1 = value; }
   }
}
```

И обращайтесь из разных форм к этому полю: `FormValuesHolder.Str1`

Comment: А разве это не глобальный объект, который нарушает ключевые принципы ООП?